# Отображение информации в полях "да/нет" при помощи чекбоксов в Crystal Reports

Tags: crystalreport, crystal

Вывожу таблицу в Crystal Reports, в ней есть 3 колонки, в которых информация булевого типа - может быть либо 1, либо 0. Хотелось бы как-нибудь превратить эти 0 и 1 и в изображения, то есть чтобы был чекбокс, в котором стояла галочка (или крестик), если значение 1, или чекбокс пустой, если значение 0. Слышал, что это можно сделать при помощи OLE-объектов, но как точно, не знаю. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://blogs.sap.com/2012/05/18/how-to-display-a-check-box-and-a-radio-button-in-crystal-report-2011/

Нашел неплохой способ работы при помощи шрифта Wingdings. Он работает.

Но вдруг есть еще какие-нибудь хорошие и удобные способы?